# Should grub be removed before reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I once installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. I then removed Ubuntu by formatting the partition. Ubuntu was gone but the grub remained. Should I remove grub before installing Ubuntu again?

Comment: I wouldn't, If you re-install ubuntu again just like you did last time it will just replace the existing grub anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do install, grub gonna be update with it.
After, if you install a new kernel or remove one directly from your system, you need to update grub manually with :
update-grub

Comment: The process of installing a kernel normally causes GRUB's configuration file to be updated automatically; there should be no need to manually run `update-grub`. If there is such a need, something is broken.

Comment: For install yes, but for remove ? When i install proxmox on a server, after install the Proxmox kernel, i don't need to update grub, but when i remove the debian kernel, i need to update it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't remove it. Your current GRUB will be simply overwritten.